# What does it mean for a loop to be shrunk?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, effective-field-theory

I am trying to follow the proof of the Appelquist-Carazzone decoupling theorem ([PhysRevD.11.2856](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.11.2856)) and am having a hard time at it.

One of the things that confuses me is what is meant by 'shrinking a loop diagram'.

On the second paragraph of page 4, the authors argue the following:

Some subgraph (of a Feynman diagram with $n$ external legs) with $F$ external legs behaves like $m^{4-F}$ in the limit $m \to \infty$. If I'm correct, this follows from simple power counting and from the fact that they assume that this subgraph is convergent. The authors then state that *"Scaling m to infinity corresponds to shrinking the subgraph S to a point..."*

At first I thought that this was a convoluted way of saying that, after having understood the assymptotic behaviour of the Feynman Integral we could just treat that subgraph as an effective vertex. However, later they mention (I'm paraphrasing)

*"The overall degree of divergence of the reduced graph (the whole graph but with the subgraph shrunken to a point), $d_R=4-n-(4-F)=F-n$, is cut off by the shrunken
graph S which, at high enough momentum, ceases
to act like a point. Thus, the behavior of the
entire graph G, for $k \ll m$ is $m^{4-F}m^{F-n}=m^{4-n}$".*

This makes clear that my initial thoughts were not all that were to it. How does the 'shrunken graph' cut off the initial degree of divergence? Why isn't the initially calculated $d_R=F-n$ the final overall degree of divergence of the entire graph in the case where the subgraph is convergent?

I'm probably missing way more than I realize and appreciate any insights.